# Eager loading GRPC Endpoints in ASP.net Core 3.1

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

is there a way to eagerly load GRPC Endpoints, so that the class' services are resolved upon application start? I currently register GRPC endpoints like this:

```
public class Startup {

    ...

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
      if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app.UseRouting();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapGrpcService<GrpcEndpointImpl>();
        ... More endpoints
      });
    }
}

public class GrpcEndpointImpl() {

    public GrpcEndpointImpl(ExampleService service) {
       ....
    }

}
```

I would like ExampleService to be resolved as soon as I start the application. I was not able to find any information in the docs. I looked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Any suggestions are appreciated.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving the class' dependency in my Configure method like this:

```
public class Startup {

    ...

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
      if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app.UseRouting();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapGrpcService<GrpcEndpointImpl>();
        ... More endpoints
      });
      app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ExampleService>(); // Note this line here
    }
}

public class GrpcEndpointImpl() {

    public GrpcEndpointImpl(ExampleService service) {
       ....
    }

}
```